# Re-running failed TestNG tests programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, testng

I was wondering if there was any easy way to re-run failed TestNG tests programmatically? I know TestNG provides a testng-failed.xml which is easy to run as a testng test. Should I just read in the testng-failed.xml file and run it that way or is there a simpler way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably the easiest way since the file already contains all the information necessary to rerun only the tests that failed.